# Adding a new Worksheet in its Alphabetically correct position

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a Workbook with a number of Worksheets, currently 6 but this will increase in the future. The Tabs / Worksheet names are in Alphabetical order, with a "Template" sheet at the end.

I am cloning that Template sheet & creating a new Worksheet with the name specified by the user, but how can I insert it into the Workbook so it is in the correct position Alphabetically ?

Comment: See:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/sortws.aspx

Comment: I did see that originally, thanks, but I thought it just seemed so long-winded for something that certainly seems like it should be simple and straightforward :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the workbook is already sorted and that a new sheet must be inserted in the alphabetical order, copied from a template sheet. The following code will do that:

```
Sub InsertSheet(name As String)
Dim i
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).name >= name Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    ActiveSheet.name = name ' can fail if sheet already exists
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly the idea I was looking at last night, Paul, but couldn't get it to work ... I was using the Name and couldn't get it accepted ... this works perfectly using the Index, I should have realised !!!

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative.  To sort the sheets **after** a new worksheet has been added:

```
Sub SheetSorter()
    Dim ary() As String, I As Long
    ReDim ary(1 To Sheets.Count)

    For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
        ary(I) = Sheets(I).Name
    Next I

    Call VBA_Sort(ary)

    For Each a In ary
        Sheets(a).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next a
End Sub

Public Sub VBA_Sort(InOut() As String)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long, _
        Hi As Long, Temp As Variant
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(I) > InOut(I + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(I) > InOut(I + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```